# Ping works, but ssh isn't even getting logged

Tags: ssh, docker

I can ping from my PC on lan or mac on WiFi, but when I run ssh it doesn't even appear in the logs. (sudo journalctl -u ssh)

I had installed zero-tier an a docker container I'm thinking this is the culprit. I removed the container, but maybe the damage is done...?

Netstat shows, "tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22"
The server can successfully SSH out to a different device or ping 8.8.8.8

I'm not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, theres a new thing called UFW I was trying iptables. anyway for posterity or for mods to laugh at me..

'sudo ufw disable'

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking at iptables and scratching my head for days!